# How can I re-enable the weapon wheel?

Tags: pc, assassins-creed-4-black-flag

In Assassin's Creed 4, the weapon wheel is gone by default on the PC. This can create problems when selecting throwing knives, for example. In addition, those who don't have a scroll wheel have trouble selecting tools.

Comment: I didn't even know there was a weapon wheel on PC... why was it disabled?

Comment: @JLaBella the weapon wheel was disabled in the place of pressing 1-8 to select tools and weapons. On consoles there is a weapon wheel though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open the `Assassin4.ini` file under `My Documents\Assassins Creed IV Black Flag`
2. Find the following lines:

```
PadUp=-1
PadRight=-1
PadDown=-1
PadLeft=-1
```

and replace them with

```
PadUp=72
PadRight=77
PadDown=80
PadLeft=75
```

This will allow you to access the weapon wheel shown in the console versions by using the number pad keys 2, 4, 6, and 8.

Save this file and restart the game to finish the process.

[Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/assassinscreed/comments/1rkms5/psa_solution_to_ac4_black_flag_throwing_knife_bug/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bind the tool (horizontal) wheel to your two side mouse buttons instead of the numpad keys suggested in this [other answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/146200) (assuming you even have a mouse with side buttons, of course), you can make the following changes to `My Documents\Assassins Creed IV Black Flag\Assassin4.ini`:

```
PadRight=259

PadLeft=260
```